# An animation which doesn't work although there is no error [Python]

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am coding a random walk i second dimension in Python. I would like to animate how it "grows". I wanted to use the `animation.FuncAnimation` from `matplotlib` but unfortunately it doesn't work as I would like. There is no error however and I used `%matplotlib tk` in iPython console.
My code:

```
def random_walk_animated_2D(n, how_many = 1):

    possible_jumps = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, -1]])
    where_to_go = np.random.randint(4, size = n)
    temp = possible_jumps[where_to_go, :]
    x = np.array([[0, 0]])
    temp1 = np.concatenate((x, temp), axis = 0)
    trajectory = np.cumsum(temp1, axis = 0)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(xlim = (np.amin(trajectory, axis = 0)[0], np.amax(trajectory, axis = 0)[0]), 
                  ylim = (np.amin(trajectory, axis = 0)[1], np.amax(trajectory, axis = 0)[1]))
    line, = ax.plot([], [], lw = 2)

    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        return line,

    def animate(i):
        line.set_data(trajectory[i, 0], trajectory[i, 1])
        return line,

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func = init, 
                                   frames = 200, interval = 30, blit = True)
    plt.show()
```

Unfortunately nothing happens after running that function.
[image: Screenshot of the plot]

Later I would like to add the possibility of generating more than one random walk in the plot (I mean I would like them to be generated simultaneously). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to draw a line through a single point.
If you want to plot a line plot, the argument to `plot` or the line's `set_data` method must have at least two points.

Instead of `line.set_data(trajectory[i, 0], trajectory[i, 1])` you probably want

```
line.set_data(trajectory[:i, 0], trajectory[:i, 1])
```

to plot a line through all points up to the `i`th point.

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing :(

Comment: If you don't see an animation if you corrected the code itself it is because you loose the reference to the animation. Let your function return the animation. When run in IPython you don't necessarily need `plt.show()`.